# Multiple AsyncTasks load the same WebView

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-1.6-donut

I'm trying to run many AsyncTasks to do loadData() on the same WebView. For example, I have 3 threads with 3 contents: "One", "Two", "Three" and a WebView with content "abc". (like the code below)

After 3 tasks finished, I want the WebView has content: "abcOneTwoThree". The idea of this code is that three threads will append its content to WebView at anytime, so the result could be "abcTwoOneThree" or "abcTwoThreeOne", etc ...

I read many concurrency articles but still don't understand how to implement this. This is my code. It just prints "abcThree".

```
public class UsingSameWebViewActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private Button button1;
    private WebView webView;
    private String result;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        result = "abc";
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        final String[] contents = {"One", "Two", "Three"};
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            final FooTask task = new FooTask(webView, result);
            task.execute(contents[i]);
        }
    }

    private class FooTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private final WebView resultView;
        private String result;

        // This is what I try to make it work right.
        private synchronized String getResult() {
            return result;
        }

        public FooTask(final WebView resultView, final String result) {
            this.resultView = resultView;
            this.result = result;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(final String... params) {
        // Do a long time work randomly then returns a string.
            return params[0];
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final String content) {
            result = getResult() + content;
            resultView.loadData(result, "text/html", "utf-8");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `private String result;` line from the Async Task class.

Comment: It works but what if FooTask is not inner class. I need to pass 'result' to FooTask as in my code?

Comment: Then make `result` a `static` member of the `async task`. Your problem essentially is that you are appending your content with an empty string, make it static and it should work.

Comment: ... but using static is quite weird. :| don't know if it is a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing much to do here.. just add this line `task.execute(contents[i]);`
 in `postExecute()` of `AsynTask` and make contents[i] as a class variable.. `task.execute(contents[i]);` call this twice since you want it to do "one" and "two"

Comment: No, I want each task appends its content to result variable then load it on WebView immediately. i.e. Task A appends 'One' to result, Task B appends 'Two' to result, ... the order is not important. If I misunderstood your answer, please add some code.

Comment: Thats what i'm trying to say.. You can call asyncTask inside postExecute multiple times.. and it probably will serve your purpose..

Answer (score 1):

In `onPostExecute()` you want to "return" your result somewhere. This is to say `FooTask` needs a place to put its result. A likely candidate would be some sort of method `FooTask` can call on its caller to place the result. If you do this note that the method must be `synchronized`, otherwise some of the returns may be lost.

Alternately you could give `FooTask` a `Handler` that it can send a `Message` to with the result. In this case, you will not need to synchronize anything since all the `Message`s will be sent to the main/UI thread which will process them serially.